# How to change source level in eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to create a Google App project on Eclipse Juno 32 bits.

I got the following syntax error when I hover on the line @SuppressWarnings("serial") in the 
app servlet:

```
syntax error , annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
```

I have JDK 1.8 installed.

Comment: Java 8 support requires Eclipse Luna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no support for Java 8 in Eclipse Juno; you need to download the latest release of Eclipse (Luna). Then you'll need to modify the `eclipse.ini` file to make sure Eclipse is running in at least a Java 7 JVM (you can use your JDK 8 if you want), according to [these instructions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Finally, right-click on your project in Eclipse and choose Properties, then select the Java Compiler section to check the compliance level.

Comment: Explanation: Luna [won't run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500488/does-eclipse-4-4-luna-require-java-1-7) on Java 1.6, that's why we need to configure it to use 1.7 or higher.